# Nebula Grid Show Item and centre it

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, nebula

Can I get a Nebula `Grid` to show an item and centre it in the available space?

I'm using the `showItem()` function in the grid, and it just seems to scroll the table by the shortest possible amount to show the row.

I tried adding a few rows on to lessen the annoyance of it sitting right at the top but of course you can't predict whether it will be at the top or the bottom after the call to `showItem` so this doesn't work.

Glen x

Answer (score 1):

The `showItem(Item)` API is from `AbstractTreeViewer` in JFace, and is not Nebula-specific.

There is no API for what you need. You could work around it by adding extra items, showing a "further" item (to simulate the centering), then show your initial item again.

Sorry. :-(

Comment: I don't think you can work around it like that. You need to know how many rows are showing on the screen as a starting point, i'm not even sure if you can do that.